# seg fault at boost::smart_pointer

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I got the following segmentation fault:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000000000040fbf6 in release (this=<value optimized out>, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>)
at /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:145
145             dispose();
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install boost-filesystem-   1.41.0-11.el6_1.2.x86_64 boost-program-options-1.41.0-11.el6_1.2.x86_64 boost-system-1.41.0-11.el6_1.2.x86_64 bzip2-libs-1.0.5-7.el6_0.x86_64 glibc-2.12-1.80.el6.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.6-4.el6.x86_64 libstdc++-4.4.6-4.el6.x86_64 lzo-2.03-3.1.el6.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000040fbf6 in release (this=<value optimized out>, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>)
at /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:145
#1  boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count (this=<value optimized out>, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>)
at /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:217
#2  0x00007f13fad83dab in boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>, void*, bool) ()
 from /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.40.0
#3  0x000000000042e191 in boost::thread_specific_ptr<infrastructure::tfeed::sequenced_data_queue_element_t::mem_prealloc>::release (this=<value optimized out>)
at /usr/local/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:95
#4  0x000000000042ed43 in  infrastructure::tfeed::sequenced_data_queue_element_t::operator new (size=16)
at ../../../infrastructure/include/tfeed/tfeed_multicast_defs.h:120
```

Also, I got a similar seg fault in another thread:

```
(gdb) thread 5
[Switching to thread 5 (Thread 0x7f122e1fe700 (LWP 7547))]
#0   0x000000000040fbf6 in release (this=<value optimized out>, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>)
at /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:145
145             dispose();
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000040fbf6 in release (this=<value optimized out>, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>)
at /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:145
#1  boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count (this=<value optimized out>, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>)
at /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:217
#2  0x00007f13fad83dab in boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>, void*, bool) ()
from /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.40.0
#3  0x000000000042e591 in release (q_elem=<value optimized out>) at /usr/local/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:95
#4  infrastructure::tfeed::sequenced_data_queue_element_t::operator delete (q_elem=<value optimized out>)
at ../../../infrastructure/include/tfeed/tfeed_multicast_defs.h:144
```

this happened while using the boost's thread specific pointer at  `/usr/local/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:95`  at (set_tss_data() call below)

```
    T* release()
    {
        T* const temp=get();
                   detail::set_tss_data(this,boost::shared_ptr<detail::tss_cleanup_function>(),0,false);
        return temp;
    }
```

and futher at sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp(at dispose())

```
void release() // nothrow
{
    if( atomic_exchange_and_add( &use_count_, -1 ) == 1 )
    {
        dispose();
        weak_release();
    }
}
```

I am using thread specific pointer while specialized new and delete calls for a datastructure(sequenced_data_queue_element_t). As this new and delete are called from multiple threads:

```
  class sequenced_data_queue_element_t
  {
    public:
    sequenced_data_queue_element_t() {
    }
   ~sequenced_data_queue_element_t() {
        delete data;
    }

unsigned char* data;
uint32_t data_len;


typedef struct mem_prealloc
{
    struct mem_prealloc* next;
} mem_prealloc_t;

static boost::thread_specific_ptr<mem_prealloc_t> mem_prealloc_q_head;

static void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    mem_prealloc_t* q_elem;
    if (UNLIKELY(mem_prealloc_q_head.get() == NULL))
    {
        /* allocate PREALLOC_BATCH elems at a time */
        for (int i=0; i < MEM_PREALLOC_BATCH; i++)
        {
            q_elem = (mem_prealloc_t*)malloc(size);
            q_elem->next = mem_prealloc_q_head.release();
            mem_prealloc_q_head.reset(q_elem);
            cur_mem_prealloced += size;
        }
    }

    q_elem = mem_prealloc_q_head.release();
    mem_prealloc_q_head.reset(q_elem->next);
    return (void*)q_elem;
}

static void operator delete(void* q_elem)
{
   /* C++ guarantees that an object's destructor 
    * is automatically called just before delete executes. */
  /* next reuses the first pointer of sequenced_data_element_t */
    ((mem_prealloc_t*)q_elem)->next = mem_prealloc_q_head.release();
    mem_prealloc_q_head.reset((mem_prealloc_t*)q_elem);

    if (cur_mem_prealloced > MEM_PREALLOC_MAX_BYTES)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < MEM_PREALLOC_BATCH; i++)
        {
            mem_prealloc_t* qelem = mem_prealloc_q_head.release();
            mem_prealloc_q_head.reset(qelem->next);
            free(qelem);
            cur_mem_prealloced -= sizeof(sequenced_data_queue_element_t);
            if (mem_prealloc_q_head.get() == NULL)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

};

`cur_mem_prealloced(uint64_t)` is a global variable.

What could be the possible reason triggering this bug?

Further, the stack of some other threads of the program seems to be corrupted. Also, the core dump shows unexpected code paths for those other threads.

the kernel logs shows the following error message:

```
  [7547]: segfault at 10 ip 000000000040fbf6 sp 00007f122e1fcd90 error 4
  [7531]: segfault at 10 ip 000000000040fbf6 sp 00007fffc94bcca0 error 4 in tbt[400000+a0000] in tbt[400000+a0000]
```

Can these seg faults be triggered in case of stack corruption as well?

Comment: Having a structure with data fields that are not initialized by the constructor, and who have no copy-constructor or copy-assignment functions (read about the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), alternatively about the [rule of zero](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html)) seems like a recipe for disaster to me.

Comment: A notice probably not linked with the exception cause. Is the global variable `cur_mem_prealloced` declared as an atomic one (something like boost::atomic<uint64_t>)? Otherwise there is a race condition.